# Java Spring Boot accessing Object in Service Class

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, oop, model-view-controller

new Coder here actually im a Student.

So i have a Problem here in my Class nobody can solve and since we're working from home i can't ask anyone.

Our Task is to create a simple API where we can enter our through HTML and the Spring Boot application is returning our gpa in the ServiceLayer class.

So my Problem rightnow is, i cant access the Object.size so i could itarete through an for Loop and basically sum all my elements up.

I've been stuck for almost a Week and cant find a solution for Spring Boot because we're new to the Framework.

```java
public class Student {


     // private final double anzahl = 4;

    private double mathGrade;
    private double germanGrade;
    private double englishGrade;
    private double codeGrade;
//  private double avgGrade;



    public double getMathGrade() {
        return mathGrade;
    }

    public void setMathGrade(double mathGrade) {
        this.mathGrade = mathGrade;
    }

    public double getGermanGrade() {
        return germanGrade;
    }

    public void setGermanGrade(double germanGrade) {
        this.germanGrade = germanGrade;
    }

    public double getEnglishGrade() {
        return englishGrade;
    }

    public void setEnglishGrade(double englishGrade) {
        this.englishGrade = englishGrade;
    }

    public double getCodeGrade() {
        return codeGrade;
    }

    public void setCodeGrade(double codeGrade) {
        this.codeGrade = codeGrade;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
        "mathGrade=" + mathGrade +
        ", germanGrade=" + germanGrade +
        ", englishGrade=" + englishGrade +
        ", codeGrade=" + codeGrade +
        '}';
    }
}
```

```
package com.Beispiel.math.student;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;      
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StudentController.class);

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;


    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String GetGrades(Model model) {
        Student student = new Student();
        model.addAttribute("student",student);
        return "register_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String submitGrades(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student){
        log.trace(String.valueOf(student));
        return "register_success";
    }
}
```

```
package com.Beispiel.math.student;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class StudentService {

    public String submitGrades(){
        Student student = new Student();
        for (int i = 0; i < student.getsize; i++) {
            student.getAvgGrade += student.get(i);
        }
        return String.valueOf(student.getAvgGrade());
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Registration</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div align="center">
    <h1>User Registration</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${student}" method="post">
        <label>Mathe Grade : </label>
        <input type="number" th:field="*{mathGrade}"/>

        <label>German Grade : </label>
        <input type="number" th:field="*{germanGrade}"/>

        <label>English Grade : </label>
        <input type="number" th:field="*{englishGrade}"/>

        <label>Code Grade : </label>
        <input type="number" th:field="*{codeGrade}"/><br><br><br><br>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Registration Success</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        span {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <div align="center">
        <h1>User Registration succeeded</h1>
        <span>Math Grade :</span><span th:text="${student.mathGrade}"></span>
        <span>German Grade :</span><span th:text="${student.germanGrade}"></span>
        <span>English Grade :</span><span th:text="${student.englishGrade}"></span>
        <span>Code Grade :</span><span th:text="${student.codeGrade}"></span>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's fine to attach all the code, but please. On the one hand it separates the content of the HTML from your Java class, on the other hand it indicates which property of which object you are not being able to access.

Comment: It seems like your controller is creating a single `Student` object, and then trying to treat it like a list of students.  I suspect that's where you're having trouble.  Assuming your instructor hasn't told you to use a database or file to persist data, it's probably safe to create and/or maintain your own list of students in the controller for now.

Comment: Oh im sorry youre right, its my first post and i got some troubles with formatting the code, Object in this Case is my Student Class and in my StudentService class im trying to sum up all the grades and returning them

Comment: @Gus Yes, its like u said, its Week 2 now our first Assignment was to create the methode to get our gpa but rightnow its to extend it with thymeleaf and html. And we shouldnt use any file or database at the moment.

Comment: ok.  So, you'll have to change your register method to add newly-registered students to a list that your server will create/maintain.  If you're struggling with the core concepts (and also need to use thymeleaf, I scanned this tutorial, and it looks pretty good:  http://itutorial.thymeleaf.org/